# What are the spells accessible from the spell wheel in LEGO Harry Potter Years 1-4?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

I'm looking for a simple list of the various spells that are acquired throughout LEGO Harry Potter Years 1-4 and accessible from the spell wheel (long press on triangle on the PS3, but I guess something similar on other platforms). I'm not asking about bought spells, just the ones you acquire with experience. It's weirdly difficult to find a simple list of them anywhere!

What I'd like for each spell ideally is:

- Colour
- Name
- What it does
- When/where it's acquired

Comment: Pretty sure the wii is the same setup.  There is a list [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960493-lego-harry-potter-years-1-4/faqs/60467#section1).  Doesn't show where you get them, but they pretty much come at the point you would expect them if you have read the books/watched the movies.

Comment: Thanks! That's close but not quite complete: on PS3 there's also a red-coloured spell and I've never worked out what it does.